# Find the indicated matrix

Tags: matrices

> $$ A=\begin{bmatrix} 2& 3\\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} $$
>     $$ B=\begin{bmatrix} 0& 4\\ -1 & 6 \end{bmatrix} $$
>   Find 2A+B

Would I go 2*2+2*3+2*2+
*4+ 0+4+-1+6?

Comment: The result should be a $2\times 2 $ matrix, not just a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply $2$ to matrix $A$, which is just multiply every number in $A$ by $2$. Then add the numbers in $A$ to $B$ respectively, that is, i. e. upper left corner number + upper left corner number.

Here's the 'upper left corner number' done (you can work out the rest yourself, better practice anyways) $2\cdot 2 = 4$. Add to matrix $B$: $$4 + 0 = 4.$$
Your final matrix will have $4$ in the upper left corner.

As comment said, it will result in such matrix. Also, you don't need to do any multiply-and-adding here because you aren't multiplying matrices by matrices, it's just number times matrix plus matrix.

Comment: Is the answer \begin{bmatrix} 4& 10\\ 3 & 14 \end{bmatrix} ?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct answer. Did I explain well? (edit: Thanks)

Comment: Of course you did!

Answer (score 1):

You are performing operations between matrices and the **result is a matrix**.
Your two operations are:

1) multiplication by a scalar, defined as
$$
k \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}\\
\end {bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
ka_{11}&ka_{12}\\
ka_{21}&ka_{22}\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$
2) sum of matrices, defined as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}\\
\end {bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11}&b_{12}\\
b_{21}&b_{22}\\
\end {bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}+b_{11}&a_{12}+b_{12}\\
a_{21}+b_{21}&a_{22}+b_{22}\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$
so the result, in your case, is:
$$2
\begin{bmatrix}
2&3\\
2&4\\
\end {bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
0&4\\
-1&6\\
\end {bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
4&6\\
4&8\\
\end {bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
0&4\\
-1&6\\
\end {bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
4&10\\
3&14\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is correct, but I just want to be sure you know that multiplication of a matrix by a scalar (in this case 2) gives you another matrix. Also, the addition of two matrices gives you another matrix. What you have proposed would just give you a number when you need the result to be a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by multiplying everything in matrix A by 2. Then add them respectively to B.

2A = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 6\\
4 & 8\\
\end{bmatrix}

B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4\\
-1 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}

2A+B=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 10\\
3 & 14\\
\end{bmatrix}